# Detect screen break point inside the component jsx itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have the following component:

```js
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Skeleton variant="rounded" animation="wave" sx={{ width: 1 }} />
      <Loading
        text="Loading..."
        sx={{ position: 'relative', background: 'none', color: 'grey' }}
        recommendedSolutions={
          <LoadingBtn
            onClick={refetch}
            variant="outlined"
            loadingIndicator="Refetching data..."
            loading={loading}
          >
            Try again
          </LoadingBtn>
        }
      />
    </Stack>
```

I want to be able to change the `direction` prop of the `Stack` component based on the screen breakpoint. The question is:

I can use the grid component to solve this problem as follows:

```js
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'block' } }}>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
          <Skeleton variant="rounded" animation="wave" sx={{ width: 1 }} />
          <Loading
            text="Loading..."
            sx={{ position: 'relative', background: 'none', color: 'grey' }}
            recommendedSolutions={
              <LoadingBtn
                onClick={refetch}
                variant="outlined"
                loadingIndicator="Refetching data..."
                loading={loading}
              >
                Try again
              </LoadingBtn>
            }
          />
        </Stack>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' } }}>
        <Stack direction="vertical" spacing={2}>
          <Skeleton variant="rounded" animation="wave" sx={{ width: 1 }} />
          <Loading
            text="Loading..."
            sx={{ position: 'relative', background: 'none', color: 'grey' }}
            recommendedSolutions={
              <LoadingBtn
                onClick={refetch}
                variant="outlined"
                loadingIndicator="Refetching data..."
                loading={loading}
              >
                Try again
              </LoadingBtn>
            }
          />
        </Stack>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

but this makes me repeat similar code, is there a way I can do it within the `direction` prop of the `Stack` component itself? it's a tough task to write that much code

Comment: You can use something like `direction={window.innerWidth > 760 ? "row" : "vertical"}`

Comment: @ChrisG won't that only work on initial render?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, the expression is evaluated anew during each render afaik (it won't re-render if the width changes but will re-render when the state does, which should be enough)

Comment: Alternatively you can avoid lots of duplicate code by storing the stuff inside the stack in a const: `const content = <><Skeleton .. /><Loading ... /></>;` and using `{content}` in the Grid version.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, what if the user resized the window?

Comment: @ChrisG, that's what I was thinking about, but I don't want to hardcode something like 760px, I want to use the breakpoints which are  defined in the theme object of the material UI

Comment: @evolutionxbox as you said, I will have then to detect screen resize inside useEffect and use useState which isn't quite handy

Comment: @Normal you won't have access to the breakpoints defined in CSS in JS.

Comment: they have them defined in a POJO, we can change those values when we change the theme context properties as well

Comment: They must add the ability to provide a function to all the components props they have, and pass the theme object as the first argument to us where we can then do things like `<ComponentX sx={{ color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey, direction: (theme) => theme.x.y.z, zIndex: (theme) => theme.z.y.x  }}>` and so on

Comment: It should be possible to read them, too. Still, you can just use the second method I pointed out.

Comment: @ChrisG, yes you're right, let me check the documentation, and I believe if I found how to use them from the theme object directly they must update the state of the component `Stack` as well